# How to delete Neo4j Graph in Graphileon Interactor without deleting users?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using `match (n) detach delete n;` in Neo4j when working with Graphileon Interactor deletes all users and functions from `Interactor`. After that you can't access Interactor anymore, even after creating a new user.

How can I delete everything from my neo4j database, exept the pre-defined functions and user profiles from Interactor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all InterActor nodes have labels that start with "IA_" , so you can also exclude them in your deletion statement.

Comment: thank you very much, good idea. May I ask you to take a look at the following question regarding InterActor? Sorry for off-topic comment. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46021766/8086529?sem=2

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to seperate the InterActor data from business data. The best way is to use a label for all business entities like :Thing. The one can do the following, and the user entities will remain in the database.

```
match (n:Thing) detach delete n;
```