# Upload files to Graphileon InterActor as node background

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graphileon

I installed Graphileon InterActor using Docker on Windows.

The [Styling Documentation](http://docs.graphileon.com/interactor/For_Dashboard_Users/Styling.html) says that files can be uploaded using the following command in style menu:

```
"image": "(%).properties.file",                   // image as node background
```

When starting InterActor I follow this command:

> You can run the InterActor image using the following command, which will also create a volume "interactor" where persistent data (the config, and files you upload to InterActor) will be stored.

And type in:

```
$ docker run -t -d -p 8000:80 --name interactor -v interactor:/persistent/ graphileon/interactor-community
778a9a7f373fc040e1adb3af446d7f2bfab9d82d15d82e5871c9658b54036a78
```

Mountpoint:

```
"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/interactor/_data"
```

I can't find the folder to store images to use them in InterActor. And if I did - how to call the path of the file?

Comment: this can be a tricky one and depends on your environment. Best contact us directly on slack . drop us a line at slack@graphileon.com pls.

Comment: @Graphileon thank you, done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on a node, EDIT, add file and give it a name. Then open Styles configuration for this node type and in the following line insert the name of the image instead of "file":

```
"image": "(%).properties.file",                   // image as node background
```